# mysql adding hours to datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

In MYSQL DB I need to check if a "datetime" field is more than 24hours (or whatever) ago in which case delete the row.

**How to add hours to datetime in mysql?**

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What about something like this :

```
delete
from your_table
where your_field <= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 day)
```

With :

- [**`now()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) : the current date time
- [**`date_sub()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) to substract 1 day to that date

Or, if you want o use 24 hours instead of 1 day :

```
delete
from your_table
where your_field <= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 24 hour)
```

Comment: Shouldnt this be `date_add`, because your not using `-1 day`? `date_sub` does the minus, `date_add` does the plus.

Answer (score 13):

You have the [Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

```
WHERE `yourDate` < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

or shorter

```
WHERE `yourDate` < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: Thanks. This is surprisingly working: `SELECT '2018-05-31' + INTERVAL 1 DAY;`

Answer (score 3):

there is the [addtime()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) method in mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE 
FROM table 
WHERE datetime_field < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```